# saliency map for multi-class multi-label classification?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have found ways to do CAM/saliency map for multi class, but not multi label multi class. Do you know of any resources I can use to do it so I don't reinvent the wheel, or rather do you have advice for implementing it?

My specific use case is that I have a transfer learned ResNet that outputs a binary 1x11 vector. Each entry corresponds to presence of a certain feature in the input image. I want to be able to get a saliency map for each feature, so I can know what the network was looking at when deciding if each image has each of those features.